# Notifications bar in Delphi

Tags: delphi, notifications, vcl

I've written an application with Delphi.

This software is the notification bar. 
When notification appears, along with it, the software is also visible.

Can only notifications appear, appear without software? (Such as Windows 8.1 & 10 and Telegram)

VCL application is written.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "can only notifications appear without software"? Behind every notification icon, there is some software.

Comment: I mean, my app notification when it comes, the application window also appears. I want the application window does not appear. Only notification will appear.

Comment: @Delphi10seattle: That is possible alright. My apps only show a menu.

Comment: By default, it always works this way. Notifications don't typically show the form, unless you have some sort of code in your application which is explicitly showing it. I cannot recreate this problem in Delphi 10 Seattle, and I've been using Delphi since 7.

Comment: Also, "notification bar" is actually widely known as the "system tray". In later versions of Windows, "Notifications" are a *completely* different unrelated thing. Unless that's actually what you're talking about.

Comment: @jerry System tray is actually a misnomer. MS don't call it that. Its correct name is notification area.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the applications main form from being displayed add the command `Application.ShowMainForm := False;` to the .dpr file (menu "Project / View source"):

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.ShowMainForm := False;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```